# Maven picking up incorrect resource path

Tags: java, maven, build

In pom.xml of my java project, I have provided resource path like this,

```
    <resource>
        <directory>C:/Softwares/apache-tomcat-7.0.82/conf</directory>
    </resource>
```

When I do mvn install, resource that is getting added is

```
C:Softwares/apache-tomcat-7.0.82/conf
```

Because of this, the following issue occurs

> Build path entry is missing: C:Softwares/apache-tomcat-7.0.82/conf

I have tried pointing the directory thru environment variable like this,

```
${env.CATALINA_HOME}/conf
```

Still the problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

It was a slash problem. The problem was resolved after I changed the path to

```
C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\conf
```